# Python can't write to cache file

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, spotipy

I'am currently working on a project using to spotify API in python. For this I'am using the spotipy library. In order for the program to work you need to have an access token. This is saved in a .cache-username file. The access token needs to be refreshed very hour. This happens automatically with the way I setup the code. The problem I'am having is that when I run the code on my windows 10 pc using python 3 it has no problem writing to the cache file and keeping the program alive, but when I run the program on my Raspberry PI also using python 3 it will crash after 30-60 minutes with the following error:

`Couldn't write token to cache at: .cache-username.`

I have already tried to give the cache file all the rights it needs by doing:

`sudo chmod +rwx .cache-username`

but that didn't solve the problem.

Does anyone know what could cause this problem and how to solve it?

The program itself:

```
import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util

clientID = "my_client_id"
clientSec = "my_client_secret_key"

# The scopes defines how much you are allowed
scope = "user-read-currently-playing"

username = "my_user_name"

# loop to keep updating
while True:
    # Gets a token for spotify and should keep it updated
    token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope, client_id=clientID, client_secret=clientSec, redirect_uri="http://localhost/Spotify/callback.php")
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)

    # Returns some data about the current playing song
    results = sp.currently_playing(market=None)

    # If there is a song playing than show the song name 
    if results:
        
        # Song info
        songName = results["item"]["name"]

        # print(songName)
    time.sleep(0.4)
```

Comment: Unfortunately the [source-code](https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/blob/44970c3348f4242be4dbadadf1d08ff5242918da/spotipy/cache_handler.py#L77) for the function that throws the error doesn't seem to distinguish between different versions of `IOError`s. Raising the error there would benefit the investigation to see if it's more specific if it's about a locked file, or permission-related.

Comment: Fixed it. I had to run the script as sudo which caused some other problems but now its working.

Answer (score 0):

NEW method : add an cache path while OAuth -> cache_path='./tokens.txt'
example -

```
oauth = spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOAuth(scope=scope, username=u, cache_path='./tokens.txt')
```

OLD method : add an cache path while prompt_for_user_token -> cache_path='./tokens.txt'
example - `util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope, client_id=clientID, client_secret=clientSec, redirect_uri="", cache_path="./tokens.txt")`

(not sure if it works with the old method)

Answer (score -2):

"OLD" method works with current version as well. Sample code:

```
util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope, client_id=clientID,
client_secret=clientSec, redirect_uri="", 
cache_path="home/pi/pythonscripts/spotipy/.cache-XXXYYYZZZ")
```